# Error on encoding large file on Node.js side after sending file from Angular-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am getting the file on server side as `console.log(body)`.

```
{ fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: '21329726_1866651723650020_188839340_o.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: './pics/',
  filename: '5146c9818ff517c426e34ad84ff3513f',
  path: 'pics/5146c9818ff517c426e34ad84ff3513f',
  size: 94093 
}
```

and then encoding by `const base64Data = body.buffer.toString("base64")`.

But for small size files, it works well but for large files it creates a problem. It is not encoding properly.

I think the problem is due to, it starts encoding before it receives the full file.

Please give me some proper way to do this.

This is my GitHub link [here](https://github.com/Rup94esh/check).

Comment: Why don't you just upload the file as it is instead of converting it to a base64?

Comment: are you getting full response in console?

Comment: @Endless I want to upload that file in `cloudinary`, and then the url of file in my database.

Comment: @Chellappan yes, If checking on angular end. And last half on checking on nodejs

Comment: Still better to upload the file as blob, file or appended into a FormData, you can convert it to base64 on the backend side...

Comment: @Endless  I don't know how to upload file as blob.

Comment: are you using any button to submit?

Comment: @Chellappan yes, I am.

Comment: disable the button until the file upload success

Comment: @Chellappan But after uploading pdf, I am waiting for about 2-3 min and then clicking the submit button.

Comment: did you check your form wheather it has full value or not?

Comment: yes, I checked, I am getting full value in form, But half when checking in nodejs

Comment: can you share you service code also

Comment: @Chellappan Please check again.

Comment: i have tried the form is not patching the file value check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-file-upload-preview-xzssvj

Comment: @Chellappan, I see,  but I don't know why. In my case it is patching.

Comment: Can you open the inspector and debug the network to check if the body of the request having enough data? If It doesn't have enough info, we can limit the scope to the frontend only.

Comment: @DatTran Please check my question again... I have solved some of it. but again caught on next problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better if you don't convert the pdf file to base64 on the frontend side since it will add request overhead as base64 is bigger in size. Better to upload the file and other request payload using html5 FormData.
Try with these changes.

directly assign the file value to your document property.

```
 this.uploadForm.patchValue({
    document: event.target.files[0]
 });
  //inside your service enrich your data with FormData ,set content-type to undefined and send it
 uploadData (uploadForm) {
    //enrich your data is FormData
    let fd= new FormData();
    // try looping through `this.form.controls` or uploadForm, to assign it property key and value dynamically
    fd.append('branch', branch_value);
    fd.append('semester', semester_value);
    fd.document('document',document_value)
    return this.http.post<RegisterResponse>('/user/upload', fd,set_header_config);
 }
```

Make sure you set the content-type correctly to undefined. I have tested uploading files in angularjs but not very familier with latest angular changes.

You can check the below blog:
http://learnwebtechs.com/2017/04/22/angularjs-multiple-file-upload-using-http-service

Comment: It is sending the file details successfully but when I am encoding it on nodeJs side it encode the file with smaller size, But for large files it is not encoding properly.

Comment: I think for large file before getting the full details, It start encoding.

Comment: I am using `const base64Data = body.buffer.toString("base64");` for encoding.

Answer (score 2):

update this code in your /server/routes/user.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
// const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, __basedir + '/upload');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    maxFileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  }
}).single('filename');

router.post('/upload', upload, (req, res) => {
  res.send('uploaded');
});

router.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

also add below line in app.js

```
global.__basedir=__dirname;
```

Comment: On which end? angular or node.

Comment: do not forget to add 'Content-Type':'application/octet-stream' header from angular post request.

Comment: And then how to fetch `req.file`.   inside 'end' function. ?

Comment: It is giving an error `throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));`

Comment: i've updated code.  i am using path package, you can use static path of file for testing.

Comment: Nothing happening on any function,  I have added my github link, Please check there.

Comment: i've tested this code via postman & it is working fine for me.