# How to add value to a key in FormGroup in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to submit a form which contains a file.
So I am using `ng2-file-upload` npm for file upload

`component.html` is-

```
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" (onFileSelected)="onFileSelected($event)">
```

and my component.ts is -

```
public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({});

  uploadForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private userService: UserServiceService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.uploadForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      branch         : ['cs', Validators.required],
      document       : [null, Validators.required],
      semester       : ['3', Validators.required],
    });


  }


  //////////// File Converted into base64/////////////////


  onFileSelected(event: EventEmitter<File[]>) {
    const file: File = event[0];

    readBase64(file)
      .then(function(data) {
         console.log(data);

        this.uploadForm.patchValue({  // Showing error -- Potentially invalid reference access to a class field via 'this.' 
          document: data
        });
      });

  }
```

I am generating base64 of file in `onFileSelected()` function and then I want to add that base64 to `document` key in my `formGroup`. But when I am trying to use `this.uploadForm.patchValue()`, It is showing an error

```
Potentially invalid reference access to a class field via 'this.'
```

I just want to add that `data` in my `document` key of `uploadForm`

Comment: Stop using anonymous functions. Use arrow functions: `then(data => { ... })`

Comment: @JBNizet, Thnx perfect , But I think `.then(function(data) {..});` and  `.then(data => { ... });` both are same

Comment: Well you might think that if you want, but it's wrong. Read the duplicate I linked to. One doesn't bind the function to this, and the other does.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanx for the reference, It works well, But when I am submitted the form only half of `base64` string is reaching to nodejs server

Comment: There must be another error somewhere then. But you haven't posted the relevant code, so...

Comment: I  already asked that question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763117/i-am-getting-half-of-base64-string-of-pdf-file-in-my-nodejs-from-angular-service?noredirect=1#comment90489059_51763117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

```
  .then(function(data) {
     this.whateva
    }.bind(this)); //here is the trick
```

or

```
  .then(data=> {//here is the trick
     this.whateva
    });
```

I didn't read rest of the code.

Comment: It works well, But when I am submitted the form only half of `base64` url is reaching to nodejs server

Comment: thats a different story (multipart upload). Ask another question with more details. Accept if it helped for described issue.

Comment: I already asked that question here but did not get any solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763117/i-am-getting-half-of-base64-string-of-pdf-file-in-my-nodejs-from-angular-service?noredirect=1#comment90489059_51763117